# Python Object Declaration Is Not Working

Tags: python

I really hope this is not a repeat...if it is, I can't find an answer anywhere, so I apologize.

Anyways, my question is, I'm writing code where, if the data I get requires a team instead of a player, I have a class (called Team) that holds two SinglePlayers (also a class), and then a few other attributes, just strings.  The problem is, when I iterate through my loop, reading the xml data and filling up my "team" variable, it seems that all the info for the SinglePlayers doesn't get reset.  This is a problem, because it is is changing that info every time I insert a new "team" into the list of "team" objects I have.  The code is long, so I'm only going to post what's relevant.

I have only been working with python again for a few days.  I have been working the past year in java and c++ so my brain has those concepts in my head of how variables and structures work.  I know python is different, so if someone could please clarify why this doesn't work, that would be amazing.  Thanks!

```
class SinglePlayer:
    entry_code = ""
    first_name = ""
    last_name = ""
    nation = ""
    seed_rank_sgl = ""
    seed_rank_dbl = ""
    entry_rank_sgl = ""
    entry_rank_dbl = ""

class Team:        
    top_player = SinglePlayer()
    bottom_player = SinglePlayer()
    entry_code = ""
    seed_rank = ""
    entry_rank = ""

def DoublesEvent(self, team_nodes):

    #Create List to store team objects
    teams_list = []

    for k in range(0, team_nodes.length):
        #Get the current node
        teams_node = team_nodes.item(k)
        team_node = team_nodes.item(k).getElementsByTagName("Player")
        top_player_node = team_node.item(0)
        bottom_player_node = team_node.item(1)

        #Make a new team object to fill and add to teams_list
        team = Team()
        team.entry_code = teams_node.getAttribute("EntryCode")

        #Top Player Info
        team.top_player.first_name = top_player_node.getAttribute("FirstName")
        team.top_player.last_name = top_player_node.getAttribute("LastName")
        team.top_player.nation = top_player_node.getAttribute("Nation")


        #Bottom Player Info
        team.bottom_player.first_name = bottom_player_node.getAttribute("FirstName")
        team.bottom_player.last_name = bottom_player_node.getAttribute("LastName")
        team.bottom_player.nation = bottom_player_node.getAttribute("Nation")

        eam.seed_rank = self.GetSeedRank(team)
        team.entry_rank = self.GetEntryRank(team)

        #Add the team to the list
        teams_list.append(team)


    return teams_list
```

Comment: The members you've created are all class attributes—like static members in C++ or Java. And, more generally, all of that code is run as part of the definition of the class itself, not the construction of each instance.

Answer (score 3):

Your *class* holds a reference to two `SinglePlayer()` instances, not your instances. Use a `__init__` method to create *new* instances for every `Team` instance:

```
class Team:        
    entry_code = ""
    seed_rank = ""
    entry_rank = ""

    def __init__(self):
        self.top_player = SinglePlayer()
        self.bottom_player = SinglePlayer()
```

As it happens, because you rebind each of the string attributes on the instances you create, you *happen* to create instance attributes for those. You'd be better off moving those into `__init__` as well and making their relationship as instance attributes explicit:

```
class Team:        
    def __init__(self):
        self.entry_code = ""
        self.seed_rank = ""
        self.entry_rank = ""
        self.top_player = SinglePlayer()
        self.bottom_player = SinglePlayer()
```

and do the same for your `SinglePlayer` class.

Comment: Not to mention that the other attributes should also be created in that manner (as it is the code works, but only by accident).

Comment: Ah!  Yes!  That makes so much sense.  In my internet research yesterday I figured that might be the problem, but I wasn't quite sure how to go about it.

Though, to do the last step, I was still having problems with that getting initialized as well, so I fixed that by changing the last line to 

teams_list.append(copy.deepcopy(team) )

Thanks again!

Comment: @user2658277: If you needed a deepcopy there, then you have more mutable attributes that are shared between the classes instead.